Prevent views from moving when another view appears
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ZStack {
            Color.red.ignoresSafeArea(.all)
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                
                VStack {
                    myView
                    mySmallView
                }
                
                Spacer()
                
                bigView
                
                Spacer()
                if status == .connecting {
                    ProgressView()
                        .progressViewStyle(CircularProgressViewStyle(tint: .white))
                        .padding()
                }
                
                Spacer()
                buttonView
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}

When the progressview appears, bigView and buttonView move slighlty. how can i prevent this from happening?
I tried removing the Spacer() but this didn't seem to help.

This method preserves the frame, so no sudden jumps.

Your code is SwiftUI. You should add that tag.

@MojtabaHosseini thank you for your answer but this is bad practice

@DuncanC done thanks

Is it bad practice? I've seen the same technique recommended elsewhere.

It seems like you might be approaching this with a mindset influenced by other frameworks like UIKit. Unlike UIView, hiding or unhiding a View in SwiftUI is not considered a bad practice; in fact, branching can be more detrimental to the render engine’s performance. There are many articles discussing this difference, but this WWDC session is a great place to start. Cheers!

Instead of sandwiching the ProgressView between two Spacer, try having just one Spacer. Then show the progress as an overlay:
Spacer()
    .overlay {
        if status == .connecting {
            ProgressView()
                .progressViewStyle(CircularProgressViewStyle(tint: .white))
        }
    }
// Spacer()

If there is any possibility that the Spacer will not reserve enough space to show the progress view, you could apply the overlay to the VStack instead. I think it needs at least 20pt.
